# Bean Validation 400 errors are returning default error page (html) instead of Response entity (json)

Tags: jersey-2.0, grizzly

I have a JUnit testsuite: GrizzlyHttpServerFactory + Jersey + Bean Validation
(jersey-container-grizzly2-servlet/jersey-bean-validation ver 2.12, grizzly-http-server ver 2.3.16,
hibernate-validator ver 5.0.0.Final)

The 400 errors generated by a ValidationException are returning Grizzly's default error page (html)
instead of the Bean Validation's Response entity (json). I've tried a ClientResponseFilter and its
entityStream also contains the html error page.

When I run the system under Tomcat, the ValidationExceptions return a Response with a json-formatted 
entity.

Any ideas on how to configure Grizzly/Jersey/Validator to NOT return the error page (html)
and put the ValidationExceptions into the Response's entityStream, just like Tomcat?

### Thanks in advance,

Mike Norman

Comment: pls. share your code I can take a look when have time. thx.

Comment: Alexey: I have put a test project up on github: https://github.com/mwnorman/grizzly-error-page

Comment: Created https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2673

Comment: @mwnorman Did you come up with any solution to this problem? I'm facing the same problem. The solution recommended by Tom doesn't work for me.

Comment: @kinkee do you see the problem even with mwnorman's test project? I guess I am missing something because that project works fine on my machine.

Answer (score 12):

After [looking into the code](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/ba7a00a3e3271219ded6faa7de7382d366637e32/containers/jersey-servlet-core/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/internal/ResponseWriter.java#L190) to which alexey pointed to for Jersey 2.13, I found out that the code path in question can be avoided by setting the property `jersey.config.server.response.setStatusOverSendError` to `"true"`.

So, as a workaround until [JERSEY-2673](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/issues/2945) is fixed, I just placed `property(ServerProperties.RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR, "true");` into my ResourceConfig class and was able to see the custom error responses in the browser.

Comment: Thanks so very much Tom - I will try that immediately1

Answer (score 1):

I went throw Jersey code and looks like it's the way Jersey works and IMO it's just a coincidence that it works fine on Tomcat.
Jersey processes the validation (and probably not only validation) errors following way:

1. *org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream#flushBuffer(boolean)*

   writes JSON error message to the Servlet OutputStream;
2. *org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter#commit()*

   calls *HttpServletResponse#sendError(int, String)*, that according to the Servlet spec:

   > ... If data has been written to the response buffer, but not returned to the client (i.e. the
   >     response is not committed), the data in the response buffer must be cleared and
   >     replaced with the data set by these methods ...

   So Grizzly clears up buffer with the JSON error and replaces it with the default error page.

I'd suggest to file an issue @ Jersey issue tracker
https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY

Comment: Created java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2673