# Jersey client is receiving the wrong response

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

Not sure what happened but I am at a loss on where my response is getting hijacked.

I am using jersey  2.15 and have had a custom exception mapper working for a little while. I have moved some code around and now my exception mapper is not working as expected but the problem appears to be that grizzly is hijacking my response.

This is the crux of my issue, if you see in my logging filter the server is correctly handling my exception and tells me that it is sending the response with application/xml. But when I print the response as a String from the client is is not the expected error message but the generic 400 error from the web server.

```
Feb 17, 2015 1:37:20 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 2 * Server responded with a response on thread Grizzly-worker(2)
2 < 400
2 < Content-Type: application/xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><constraintViolationErrorResponse><responseCode>2</responseCode><violations><path>createCustomer.arg0.customerContact</path><message>customerContact is a required field</message></violations><violations><path>createCustomer.arg0.technicalContact</path><message>technicalContact is a required field</message></violations><violations><path>createCustomer.arg0.spCustomerID1</path><message>spCustomerID1 is a required field</message></violations><violations><path>createCustomer.arg0.customerAddress</path><message>customerAddress is a required field</message></violations><violations><path>createCustomer.arg0.customerName</path><message>customerName is a required field</message></violations></constraintViolationErrorResponse>

Response is <html><head><title>Grizzly 2.3.16</title><style><!--div.header {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#003300;font-size:22px;-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;border-top-left-radius: 10px;-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;border-top-right-radius: 10px;padding-left: 5px}div.body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:#FFFFCC;font-size:16px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px}div.footer {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#666633;font-size:14px;-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;padding-left: 5px}BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;}B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;}A {color : black;}HR {color : #999966;}--></style> </head><body><div class="header">Bad Request</div><div class="body">Bad Request</div><div class="footer">Grizzly 2.3.16</div></body></html>
Media type is text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Feb 17, 2015 1:37:20 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener shutdownNow
INFO: Stopped listener bound to [localhost:9998]
```

Here is my exception mapper that handles ConstraintViolationException

```
@Provider
public class ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> {

    //private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper.class.getName());

    public Response toResponse(ConstraintViolationException exception) {
        final int violationCount = exception.getConstraintViolations().size();

        ConstraintViolation<?>[] constraintViolations = exception.getConstraintViolations().toArray(
                new ConstraintViolation<?>[violationCount]);
        Violation[] violations = new Violation[exception.getConstraintViolations().size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < violationCount; i++) {
            ConstraintViolation<?> cv = constraintViolations[i];
            Violation violation = new Violation(cv.getPropertyPath().toString(), cv.getMessage());
            violations[i] = violation;
        }

        ConstraintViolationErrorResponse responseEntity = new ConstraintViolationErrorResponse();
        responseEntity.setViolations(violations);

        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(responseEntity).build();
    }
}
```

This is the unit test I am using where it is printing out the response from the client for debugging.

```
    @Test
    public void testConstraintViolationException() {
        logger.info("testConstraintViolationException");
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        Entity<Customer> customerEntity = Entity.entity(customer, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);


        Response response = target("customer").request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).post(customerEntity, Response.class);
        if (response.getStatusInfo() != Status.OK) {

            final String res = response.readEntity(new GenericType<String>() {});
            System.out.println("Response is " + res);

            System.out.println("Media type is " + response.getMediaType());
            ConstraintViolationErrorResponse responseEntity = response.readEntity(ConstraintViolationErrorResponse.class);
            assert (responseEntity.getClass() == ConstraintViolationErrorResponse.class);
            ConstraintViolationErrorResponse constraintResponse = (ConstraintViolationErrorResponse) responseEntity;
            assert (constraintResponse.getViolations().length > 0);

            for (Violation v : constraintResponse.getViolations()) {
                logger.fine("Constraint Violation  Path -> " + v.getPath() + " Message -> " + v.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Quick note if I return ACCEPTED or OK as the response code the response is processed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755773/bean-validation-400-errors-are-returning-default-error-page-html-instead-of-re)

The problems was a configuration problem in the resource config.